# Android OnClickListener not firing on first click

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have what should be a simple task that is not working correctly. I have a button defined as follows in my xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/link1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:minWidth="256dip"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:tag="1"
/>
```

This button is connected to the following listener inside a fragment:

```
final Button link1 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.link1);
link1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                System.out.println(link1.getTag().toString());
            }
});
```

The problem I am experiencing is that this onClick method is not firing on the first click. It works from the second click onwards. This is a pretty straightforward button with a click listener, so I am not sure why the first click is not being registered.

edit: I have discovered that not only are the buttons not working until there is a first click on the screen, but the tabs of my viewpager are not scrolling or being selected until the screen is first clicked. So this means that there is currently no gesture or button press possible on the app from the start until the screen is touched first. What could be locking everything out like that?

edit2: The source of my problem is that I have set the following:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

The purpose of the code above is to remove the navigation buttons on some phones, such as the Nexus phones. Read more: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

With the above code included, the app will hide the soft buttons on the phone exactly as expected, but the app will require me to perform a touch event before the rest of the app becomes responsive. I'm going to make a new question based on this.

Comment: Where is your `onClick` defined? In which method?

Comment: In which layout Button `link1` is in Activity or in Fragment?

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K - In the fragment's layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's an old question, I've experienced it too.
Main problem was `focusableInTouchMode` property. When it was set to true, clicks weren't firing on 1st click, because element element received focus.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
    private View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contatos, container, false);
    final Button link1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.link1);
link1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                System.out.println(link1.getTag().toString());
            }
});


    }
```

Note findViewById is called on the rootView object. Good Luck

Comment: I have tried this and it did not fix the problem. Same behaviour as before.

Comment: I also had this in the onStart() method, tried moving to onCreateView and that did not fix the problem. I put a breakpoint to see when the onClickListener is being set, and it appears to happen before control is given to the user in either case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to assign a method to your button in the XML layout, using the `android:onClick` attribute.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/link1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:minWidth="256dip"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:tag="1"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
/>
```

Then, define the method in your activity:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    System.out.println(view.getTag().toString());
}
```

I hope this helps.